# Select a DataRow based on two column conditions

Tags: vb.net, linq, datatable, datarow

I have a datatable that I know to be empty at the beginning, but as I populate it, I am unable to get the datarow back out of it based on two column conditions, so it is doubling (or more) the number of rows.

I may be going about this wrong, but my aim is to check if the row exists in the datatable if the 2 conditions are met and then get the row if it does exist and modify it.

```
Dim qryB = From drw As DataRow In oDT_Signals.Rows
           Where drw("SG").Equals(sgrp) AndAlso drw("EP").Equals(srchPt)
           Select drw

Dim rslt = qryB.SingleOrDefault

If IsNothing(rslt) Then
    ed.WriteMessage("Row does not exist")
    oDT_Signals.Rows.Add(0, 0, sgrp, rw.sPt, PtList.IndexOf(rw.sPt), rw.ePt, PtList.IndexOf(rw.ePt), "NIL", rw.Len, 0, rw.Phases, rw.Size, rw.Core, rw.Ins, rw.Temp, rw.Table, "NIL",
                            "NA", "NA", rw.mVAm, ldVal, 0, 0, rw.Zs, 0, 0, rw.ePt.X, rw.ePt.Y, rw.mVtest, 0, 0, rw.Ztest, 0, 0)

Else
    ed.WriteMessage("Row does exist")
    Dim dr As DataRow = qryB.First
    dr("LOAD") = Math.Round(ldVal + dr("LOAD"), 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
End If
```

The issue is rslt is always nothing, when I know it is not the case. Is anyone able to help me determine what I am doing wrong that is is always adding the row? The console just keeps saying "Row does not Exist".

Comment: Please don't cut the leading whitespace off the first line of your code and leave it on the rest. It makes it harder to read the code and it's very easy to avoid, either in VS or in the SO editor. Make the effort to make it as easy as possible for us to help you, which includes making your code as readable as possible.

Comment: If you prefer query syntax then it's your prerogative to use it but you could write that query much more succinctly using function syntax. Taking my answer into account, the first two lines could be replaced with this: `Dim rslt = oDT_Signals.AsEnumerable().SingleOrDefault(Function(drw) drw.Field(Of String)("SG") = sgrp AndAlso drw.Field(Of String)("EP") = srchPt)`.

Comment: Your use of `First` in the `Else` block is worse than pointless. If you are in the `Else` block then you already know for a fact that the query matched one row and `rslt` already refers to that row. What's the point of executing the same query a second time to get the same row that you already have? That also means that you don't need the unrealised query to be able to use later, so using function syntax rather than query syntax, as I showed above, is possible.

Comment: i was just trying everything I could to get that row. I knew it was stupid, but just cannot figure out why it doesn't find it. I have tried a lot of methods and that was a hangover. You are correct and it is gone now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested to be sure but I'm fairly certain that the issue is your use of the `Object.Equals` method, which will test for reference equality. If value equality is what you're interested in, test for that.  Change this:

```
Where drw("SG").Equals(sgrp) AndAlso drw("EP").Equals(srchPt)
```

to something like this:

```
Where drw.Field(Of String)("SG") = sgrp AndAlso drw.Field(Of String)("EP") = srchPt
```

If the columns don't contain `Strings`, change the generic type of the `Field` calls.

Comment: Thank you for trying nut this does not work either. I am not sure what you mean about the whitespace issue sorry, but i will try to do better. Either way I just keep getting no rslt... I have tried both your query and function syntax to no avail.

Comment: In that case, I would suggest that there is no match. You should ditch the LINQ for the time being and just use a standard loop. You can then see exactly what values are being compared for each row and you will be able to see exactly which row, if any, you think should be matching and exactly what values are being used at the time. For instance, maybe your `sgrp` and/or srchPt` variables don't contain what you think they do.

Comment: With regards to the whitespace, if you select code from the first character in the first line to the last character in the last line then you are chopping off the leading whitespace on that first line and leaving it on others. Just look and you can see it with your own eyes. You can avoid that by depressing *Alt* when selecting to get an arbitrary rectangular block, removing white space from all lines. Alterantively, you can select all but the first line after pasting and then click the *Code Sample* button repeatedly to remove leading whitespace characters four at a time.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can see it but you can click on the link where it says that I edited your question to see the changes I made and see why it is now more readable.

Comment: You were correct all along. srchpt was not what I thought it was. Thank you so much.